# Data Properties to run OPTICS in ELKI

Tags: elki, optics-algorithm

I have been trying to run "OPTICS" algorithm on my data, my data has around 40000 records which each of them has 3 attributes + plus the ID for each record. 
the interesting thing is that when I run the "OPTICS" just on 3 attributes" ELKI gives me an ERROR regarding "stackoverflow" but when I run it including the 4 attributes it runs with out any problem. 
so is the problem with my data?!

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you are running 0.6.0? Then please use the latest version.

There was a known issue with 0.6.0 with *duplicates* where the sorting algorithm could yield a stack overflow (due to inefficient handling of ties).

Your ID attribute probably makes each distance unique.

How many duplicates do you have in your data?